# What Scripture might support Bunyan? - "Christ, as Priest, continually intercedes; Christ, as Advocate, in case of great transgression, pleads"."

Tags: 1-john

**Context**:

I'm currently reading "Gentle and Lowly" by Dane Ortlund. On page 90 there is this quote by Ortlund:

"Apparently, he [Christ] intercedes for us given our general sinfulness, but he [Christ] advocates for us in the case of specific sins.

Bunyan explains it like this: Christ, as Priest, goes before, and Christ, as an Advocate, comes after. Christ, as Priest, continually intercedes; Christ, as Advocate, in case of great transgressions, pleads. Christ, as Priest, has the need to act always, but Christ, as Advocate, sometimes only."

My question is this:

**What Scripture would support Bunyan's statement that Christ is an Advocate only in the case of "great transgressions"?** I would have thought that Christ is an advocate for all of our sins (not just "great transgressions") based on the below verses.

1 John 2:1-2 (CSB)

> <sup>**1**</sup> My little children, I am writing you these things so that you may not sin. **But if anyone does sin, we have an advocate with the Father — Jesus Christ the righteous one.** <sup>**2**</sup> He himself is the atoning sacrifice for our sins, and not only for ours, but also for those of the whole world.

Comment: This is extremely imprecise language.  Does this refer to Jesus as (1) parkeletos" (1 John 2:1) or "mesites" (2 Tim 2:5).  Both are translated "Advocate" in English but with importantly different shades of meaning.  The distinction made by Bunyan is not made in Scripture.

Comment: Thanks @Dottard. I've also looked at the Greek definitions for "advocate" in 1 Jn 2:1, and "intercede" in Heb 7:25, & both seem unclear. Ortlund:
"Intercession has the idea of mediating between 2 parties, bringing them together. Advocacy is similar but has the idea of aligning oneself with another. An intercessor stands between two parties; an advocate doesn’t simply stand in between the two parties but steps over and joins the one party as he approaches the other...  advocacy is a neglected teaching in the church today, and it flows straight from the depths of Christ’s very heart. (p. 87)"

Comment: Hi David, welcome to the site! It would be better to tone the question title down a bit -- remove the all caps, remove the two question marks, and make the title more concise. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Robert. Hopefully it reads better now.

Comment: I would actually take more issue with "Christ, as priest, has the need to act always" since he has sat down at the right hand, having completed his priestly work.

Comment: I agree @MikeBorden. Ortlund says on p 89 that Heb 7:25 means that Christ is always interceding for his people. Heb 7:23-24 seems to suggest that the "always" is used to contrast to the everlasting priesthood of Christ with the temporary priesthood of the Levites who died:
Hebrews 7:23-25 (CSB)
23 Now many have become Levitical priests, since they are prevented by death from remaining in office. 24 But because he remains forever, he holds his priesthood permanently. 25 Therefore, he is able to save completely those who come to God through him, since he always lives to intercede for them.

Comment: Heb 7:25 introduces a third word, ἐντυγχάνω, different from the other two again.  Thus, there are three words: entugchano, parakletos, mesites.  we need to ask a more specific question here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following you @Dottard . What do you think Heb 7:25 means, given it's context, and the meaning of the Greek words? - Therefore, he is able to save completely those who come to God through him, since he always lives to intercede (ἐντυγχάνω) for them.

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  We have three words for Christ's work of "interceding", advocacy, etc.  Which of these are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

I think Bunyan would say that the verse you are quoting supports his position. It comes down to what 1 John 2:1 means by sin:

> My little children, I am writing you these things so that you may not sin.

Is John writing this so that we can be perfect? If so, then Jesus is indeed advocating for all our imperfections. But John has set himself a rather futile task.

Or is John wishing to keep us from our - to keep with Bunyan's term - great transgressions. Then John is setting himself a more likely task, and Bunyan is using quite plain exegesis.

1 John does use the word "sin" in quite a complex way, and I think my second reading is plausible. Thus if one views "sin" in verse one as "great transgressions" and "sin" in verse two as all moral imperfections, then Bunyan's quote is just a restatement of 1 John.

--

However, I can more directly look at Bunyan's words [here](http://acacia.pair.com/Acacia.John.Bunyan/Sermons.Allegories/Jesus.Christ.Advocate/5.html), and the key thing the sufficiency of the sacrifice - the sacrifice cleanses the elect from all punishment. We only need advocacy for our consciences, and against the devil. It is a much more responsive role in Bunyan's eyes.

"If any man sin, we have an advocate with the father" - yes. But that advocate will only be advocating when we take our sins to Jesus and ask Him to advocate for us. We will not do this with our (e.g.) grumpy morning thoughts (until we see them as great transgressions) and thus they are dealt with by the blood, but only our great transgressions will be advocated for. For it is our great transgressions that need advocating for, lest they make us weak.

But where is Bunyan's scriptural basis for the idea that advocacy is something to be requested? It is in the Psalms:

> (1.) Wouldest thou know whether Christ is thine Advocate or no? I ask, Hast thou entertained him so to be? When men have suits of law depending in any of the king's courts above, they entertain their attorney or advocate to plead their cause, and so he pleads for them. I say, hast thou entertained Jesus Christ for thy lawyer to plead thy cause? "Plead my cause, O Lord," said David (Psa 35:1); and again, "Judge me, O God, and plead my cause" (Psa 43:1). This, therefore, is the first thing that I would propound to thee: Hast thou, with David, entertained him for thy lawyer, or, with good Hezekiah, cried out, "O Lord, I am oppressed; undertake for me" (Isa 38:14).